# jQuery Autocomplete not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete with JSON but the resulting data is not displaying correctly. If you go to http://whatsmybeer.com and type in "firestone" you get a drop down list that reads "Undefined" with the correct number of results but the JSON is not displaying correctly. You can see an example of the the JSON output which is called from the javascript http://whatsmybeer.com/search.inc.php?beer=firestone&callback=?

My JS script to display the JSON results.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#REMOTE" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                url = "search.inc.php?beer=" + request.term;
                $.getJSON(url + '&callback=?', function(data) {
                    response(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong with the parsing?

Comment: your site almost crashed firefox for me. So where are you doing the parsing?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592048/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-response

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643309/jquery-autocomplete-json-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd `limit the search result to 10` or whatever - first response with thousends or whatever number of beers you have kills the browser when it tries to process the data for display.

Further I'd set the `minLength` option of `autocomplete` to `2` as putting one letter is overkill for server side as if someone will enter 'a' it will probably return half of the database (if you won't like to include the returned amount limit) adding autocomplete after entering 2nd letter is more natural especially with large databases.

**And most importantly** - you need to have your JSON response formatted in the right way.

you return object with:

```
{ 
    beer_name: "name" 
}
```

and you should return:

```
{
    label: "autocomplete display value",
    value: "input value after selection"
}
```

if label and value are the same it should be enough to provide just the `label` and you should be able to safely omit duplicating it in `value`

Comment: Great I added the limit and also minLength. Label and Value are the same which is why I only have beer_name: "name". Is there still something wrong with the JSON format?

Comment: property name HAVE to be value or label - it can't return beer_name as it won't work I'm afraid - alternatively you can pass array of names `["beer name 01", "beer name 02", ... ]` - this is requirement of autocomplete module of jqueryUI and you have to comply to it to have it working.

Comment: That was my problem. I removed the label and just returned the array names like this ["beer name 01", "beer name 02", ... ]. The script works now. Thanks Tom.

Comment: always glad to help when beer is involved :)